# AngularJS concatenate two functions

Tags: angularjs

I have two factories (because it is more readable) and one controller.
I do not know if it is possible, but I want to sent the result of the two factories in one variable.

**code**

```
vm.result = [];
vm.validate = validate;
function validate(password1, password2) {
    vm.result = comparePasswordFactory.compare(password1, password2) + validNumberFactory.valid(password1);
    return vm.result;
}
```

compare returns:

```
return {
     color: 'green',
     text: 'Passwords match',
     validate1: 'true'
};
```

valid returns:

```
return {
    text: 'Number should be between 12 and 45',
    validate2: 'false'
};
```

I do not think what I wrote is correct.
But, is this possible and/or is it a good option ?

Comment: What is the result from your factories? It looks like bools, but the "+" operator doesn't work with bools. Use "&&".

Answer (score 1):

in order to validate using both functions you have to read and compare its `validate1` / `validate2` properties

```
var passwordOK = comparePasswordFactory.compare(password1, password2).validate1 === 'true';
var numberOK = validNumberFactory.valid(password1).validate2 === 'true';
vm.result = passwordOK && numberOK;
```

**tip**: better way would be to use `boolean` values instead of string, eg.

```
return {
    validate: false
}
```

**pro way**: consider using consistent api in your factories, then you could do something like:

```
var validators = [comparePasswordFactory, validNumberFactory];
var isValid = true;
for(var i=0;i<validators.length;i++){
    if(!validators[i].validate.call(this, password1, password2)){
        isValid = false;
        break;
    }
}
vm.result = isValid;
```

then you could easily add another validator (*notice that all factories must implement `validate` method*)

Comment: Did you wanted to say `validate` variable ?

Comment: no, validate method (which is now `compare` in password factory and `valid` in number factory)